# R: initial condition error in deSolve-package

Tags: r, ode

I just started working with deSolve. For some reason a simple example code gives me this error message:

> Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) :    The number of
>   derivatives returned by func() (1) must equal the length of the
>   initial conditions vector (4)

I use the following example code:

```
library(deSolve)
model <- function (time, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)), {
    dY1 <- -k1*y1*y2 + k2*y3
    dY2 <- k2 * y3 - k1*y1*y2
    dY3 <- -k2*y3-k3*y3+k1*y1*y2
    dY4 <- k3*y3
    list(dY1,dY2,dY3,dY4)
  })
}
yini <- c(y1 = 1,y2=1,y3=0,y4=0)
parms <- c(k1=0.1,k2=0.1,k3=0.1)
times <- seq(0, 100, 1)
out <- ode(y=yini, times=times, func=model, parms=parms)
plot(out)
```

As you can see I have exactly 4 derivatives and 4 initial conditions defined in yini. Therefore, I cannot interpret this error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `model` the last line has to be:

```
list(c(dY1,dY2,dY3,dY4))
```

So the output has to be concatenated `c()` in a vector. This is required by the `deSolve`package.

So the whole function looks like this:

```
model <- function (time, y, parms) {
  with(as.list(c(y, parms)), {
    dY1 <- -k1*y1*y2 + k2*y3
    dY2 <- k2 * y3 - k1*y1*y2
    dY3 <- -k2*y3-k3*y3+k1*y1*y2
    dY4 <- k3*y3
    list(c(dY1,dY2,dY3,dY4))
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for overlooking the obvious!